# error in C for simulated templade

Tags: c++, c, dev-c++

I have this error in Dev C. It says there is an error regarding pointers, but I'm not using pointers.

> [Error] invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]

The error is in this line:

```
E=suma1 + distancias [x,y];
```

(Where `suma1` and `E` are integers, and `distancias` is a matrix)

Comment: Try `distancias[x][y]`. Comma does something different in C/C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `x,y` is actually a single value in C and C++. It *evaluates* both `x` and `y` but *gives* you  the single value `y`. You can see this in action if you try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
    int a;
    a = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    printf ("%d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

which will output `5`.

Hence what your current expression `distancias [x,y]` is being evaluated is is a simple `distancias [y]` (because evaluating `x` here has no side effects), which is why it's complaining about an `int` *pointer* being used where an `int` is expected.

The correct syntax for multi-dimensional arrays would be `distancias [x][y]`.